# Static compilation fails: dynamic STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol `tan' .. can not be used when making an executable

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, expect, static-linking

I'm trying to compile `expect` statically on my PC, but I seem to run into some strange compiling errors.

I was able to compile `tcl` statically like this:

```
./configure --disable-load --disable-shared
```

Then add to the makefile `CFLAGS` variable `-static` keyword. Now after compiling I seem to have a static tcl, and a library:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 jlumme jlumme 3284332 loka   2 11:27 libtcl8.6.a
```

After this, I configure `expect`:

```
./configure --with-tclconfig=${TCL_DIR}/unix --disable-shared --disable-load
```

And then compile (first dynamic):

```
$ gcc  -pipe -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall   -Wl,--export-dynamic  -o expect exp_main_exp.o -L/home/jlumme/Downloads/compile/expect5.45 -lexpect5.45 -L/home/jlumme/Downloads/compile/tcl8.6.4/unix -ltcl8.6   -lieee -lm -lpthread -lz
```

The result looks ok:

```
$ file expect
expect: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=a613c260944117f43bcaebc43c51c421dce273a7, not stripped
```

But now if I want to attempt a static compilation, I get errors that I dont understand:

```
 gcc  -pipe -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall   -Wl,--export-dynamic  -o expect exp_main_exp.o -L/home/jlumme/Downloads/compile/expect5.45 -lexpect5.45 -L/home/jlumme/Downloads/compile/tcl8.6.4/unix -ltcl8.6   -lieee -lm -lpthread -lz -static



/home/jlumme/Downloads/compile/tcl8.6.4/unix/libtcl8.6.a(tclUnixCompat.o):     In function `TclpGetGrGid':
 tclUnixCompat.c:(.text+0x41c): warning: Using 'getgrgid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
 /home/jlumme/Downloads/compile/tcl8.6.4/unix/libtcl8.6.a(tclUnixCompat.o):     In function `TclpGetGrNam':
 tclUnixCompat.c:(.text+0x31c): warning: Using 'getgrnam_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking

 <HANDFUL OF WARNINGS REMOVED>

 /usr/bin/ld: dynamic STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol `tan' with pointer equality in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a(s_tan.o)' can not be used when making an executable; recompile with -fPIE and relink with -pie
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I dont really understand what this final linking problem is, can someone help ?